# Preselecting an account for the UAC

Tags: windows-8.1, uac

Is it possible to preselect one of all the given accounts for the UAC? I have mutliple Administrator accounts but I only got the password of one of them. I need to manually select the Administrator account and enter the password every time. Is there a way to make one of the accounts the preselected one?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the credential entry and just set the prompt to consent only.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000004
```

Default value is "00000005"

This assumes you are logged in as an administrator, to function correctly.